# How to get the changes that happened in an account in a signature?

Tags: transactions, data, decode

I have a [data account](https://explorer.solana.com/address/AcMZtG8ycwSm5BXc4aoTaE82gvfpVvQjjA8dYphQ9CRe?cluster=devnet) with `187 bytes` allocated

After each signature, the data changes. Yet I can't seem to find how to get the changes in the data that happened in that account.

e.g. [this transaction](https://explorer.solana.com/tx/4sGFRQXPC2JLJgpoVgcvJWmD9hKSr1zC5U2Jp5DZn3LC51ygKEZX6UvM14Fhye8ghhV4Ltsdd3afUSeC5vcveyJW?cluster=devnet)

**instruction data: 6b 92 54 5c 84 7c 27 5c 06 03 04 03** is the data that has been passed to the program. It's possible to know the changes that happened by decoding the instruction data but it's different for each program. Is there a general way of knowing how was the data affected?

I can get the current data by getting the [account info](https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/account_info/struct.AccountInfo.html) but I can't for other epochs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and asking multiple people, the reliable way to get account data changes is by replaying/simulating the transaction and seeing the changes that occur for the account.

e.g. The behavior of the program is encoded into the program itself. A program is just eBPF bytecode. Exactly like an .exe file So simulation re-executes it identically to when the tx was run on the chain. You’ll need all historical account states (including program) next to the instruction.

Thanks to [Richard Patel](https://twitter.com/terorie_dev) for the help.